# How do you display info from a database

Tags: atk4

I have figured out how to add data from a model into a grid like the examples on the [learning section of the Agile Toolkit website](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn). But I'm looking for the correct way to show data from a database without a grid.

Say I have a news database and I want to display it as a blog style news on my home page. Can someone point me to where to begin?

Trying to make this a little more clear:
I want to display data from multiple columns from a table news. So I would need to know how to get the title, date, author, content and then repeat that for say 5 latest news articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$this->add('View',null,null,array('view/mytemplate'))
    ->setModel('MyModel')
    ->loadData(123);
```

then inside templates/defaults/view/mytemplate.html

```
<div><h2><?$title?></h2>
   <p><?$content?></p>
</div>
```

You can also use it with any view, even page.

```
$data=$model->get();
$page->template->set($data);
```

you can re-define template for your page by defining defaultTemplate function

```
function defaultTemplate(){
    return array('page/mypage');
}
```

Comment: I def overthought that. Ty for your help.

Comment: That's what first page of learning book already warns about. Don't over-think it. :)